Unable to Update React-Rendered DOM Classes with jQuery
What I Tried:
Attempted to use jQuery to update classes within the DOM rendered by a React component.
Verified that the classes I'm targeting exist in the DOM by checking their length, which
consistently returns 0.
Ensured that both the React component and the jQuery code are correctly implemented and executed.
Expectations:
Ideally, when querying for the .wpgmp-map-data-container class using jQuery, I expected the length to be 1, indicating that the class exists in the DOM and can be manipulated accordingly.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First, ensure that you have jQuery included in your project, either through a CDN or by installing it using a package manager like npm.
Here's an example of how you can use useEffect() hook to run jQuery code after a component is mounted:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'; // Import jQuery

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
  // This code will run after the component is mounted
  $('.wpgmp-map-data-container').addClass('new-class'); 
  // Add a new  class using jQuery
     }, []);      

   return (
      <div className="wpgmp-map-data-container">
     {/* Your component JSX */}
     </div>
   );
 }

export default MyComponent;
In this example:

We import jQuery at the top of the file using import $ from 'jquery';.
Inside the useEffect() hook, we execute our jQuery code. Here, we're adding a new class new-class to the element with class wpgmp-map-data-container.
The empty dependency array [] as the second argument to useEffect() ensures that this effect runs only once after the component is mounted.

However, I must emphasize again that mixing jQuery with React is generally discouraged because React manages the DOM independently. It's better to handle all DOM manipulations within React using state and props whenever possible. Using jQuery alongside React can lead to maintenance issues, as React's virtual DOM and jQuery's direct DOM manipulation can conflict with each other.
